# Парсинг xlsx на 30000 строк из php на хостинге

Tags: php, mysql, парсер, xls

Собсвенно вот задача:
Взять прайс на 30000 строк и в идеале сравнить его с существующей таблицей на 1000 строк (обновить цены , в общем).

В крайнем случае надо просто записать в отдельную таблицу содержимое xls

Я так подозреваю,что при парсинге "в лоб" скрипт отвалится на первой тысяче строк.

Есть ли какой то способ решить задачу ?
(Может можно xls напрмую в MySQL скармливать, или как вариант, держать xls файл на хосте и при запросе товара, искать цену напрямую в xls файле (через артикул).
Но для этого должен существовать какой то способ проводить поиск по xls файлу из PHP)

**xlsx** весит 1.5 Мб, при переводе в **xls** - 4.5

В общем, кто сталкивался с подобной задачей, прошу помощи, откуда вообще начинать.
Спасибо

Comment: Если есть возможность конвертировать файл в csv формат, то сделайте это, после чего читайте его порциями по 400-500 строк и используйте функцию http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: увы нет. при попытке через excel сохранить как csv Невозможно сохранить XML-данные, так как книга не содержит сопоставлений XML.
Стоит задача, сделать интерфейс для чайников, так что то-то сложнее, чем файл-сохранить как  с их стороны вряд ли подойдет

Comment: Найдите подходящую библиотеку для чтения xls. Вам нужна та, что позволит обращаться к конкретной строке. В крайнем случае, можно прочитать и все, 30к - это не так и много. Все зависит от того, как вы впоследствии данными будете распоряжаться. Вот несколько библиотек: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel, https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader.

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, нужно данные нормализовать, сделать удобное чтение, лучше в csv.
Дальше поиск можно сделать в mysql, просто записав строки. А можно по другому.
Используя битовые поля и битмапы создать битовые поля на каждое свойство.
Где свойство со значением x будет иметь битовое поле 0101011, что означает что у строк 1, 2, 4, 6 свойство имеет значение x.
Дальше когда нужно фильтровать, делаем побитовое И или ИЛИ, или комбинируем и то то. Дальше просто вычисляем позиции включенных битов, обозначающие номера строк. На одно свойство битовое поле при 30K строках будет ~3,6 килобайта.